# How do I pass values from a parent element to a child element in ReactJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I have nested react elements how do I pass values in the parent element to the child element, when the child element is not internal to the parent element.

```
React.render(
  <MainLayout>
    <IndexDashboard />
  </MainLayout>,
  document.body);
```

In this code I have some functions in the MainLayout element that I would like to be able to access in the IndexDashboard element. How do I pass those functions to the child element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the cloneElement function to modify the props of the child components:

```
#MainLayout

render: function(){ (
  var contents = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
    return React.cloneElement(child, {onSomeEvent: this.onSomeChildEvent})
  }.bind(this));

  return (
        <div>
            {contents}
        </div>
  );       
}
```

Refer to the following link for details: https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/03/react-v0.13-rc2.html

Answer (score 1):

you would typically not render children elements like that in a `React.render` call, and instead move `IndexDashboard` to the render of your `MainLayout` component so you can pass it the props it needs.

Edited per your comment: In the case of dynamically rendering children, i'd recommend passing it in as a prop based on what page youre on. I dont know if JSX supports that syntax, but you can use `React.createElement` for sure.

```
React.render(
  <MainLayout childProp={ IndexDashboard }/>,
document.body);

#MainLayout
render: function(){ (
  return (
    React.createElement(this.props.childProp, [otherProps...])
  )       
}
```

<del>I'm not sure what you mean by 'its not internal to the Parent' since it clear is being rendered with it. If you absolutely cannot move the child to the parent render function, you would want to use a flux-like architecture using a store to house the data that both `MainLayout` and `IndexDashboard` require</del>

Comment: The problem with that is the child componenet is only IndexDashboard on one page, The child component will be different on each page but it will have the same layout component.